# How can I make a "SELECT INTO" query to a new table in external database?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have 2 databases: `MainDB` (Source: `C:\Test\MainDB.accdb`) with one table (`MainDataTable`):

```
|  ID  |  NAME  |  DATE  |  
|  01  | Peter  |09-08-17|  
|  02  | Paul   |02-08-17|  
|  03  | Peter  |20-08-17|
```

and `PeterDB` (Source: `C:\Test\PeterDB.accdb`) with no tables.

I want to `INSERT` all rows from `MainDataTable` into the `PeterDB` where `Name = Peter`.

This is my code:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source = C:\Test\MainDB.accdb";
con.Open();

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * INTO PeterDB [IN C:\Test\PeterDB.accdb] FROM MainDB WHERE Name = 'Peter'; ", con);

try
{
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    con.Close();
}
```

But I can't execute that query (because of the DB source I suppose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT * 
INTO [C:\Test\PeterDB.accdb].[NewTable] 
FROM [MainDataTable] 
WHERE [Name] = 'Peter'
```

Comment: I get Unrecognized escape sequence error (because of the " \ " from C:\Test\PeterDB.accdb)

Comment: To include backslashes in a C# string literal you need to either double them up (`"C:\\folder\\file.accdb"`) or use a raw string (`@"C:\folder\file.accdb"`).